# Does Logstash maintain a registry file?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I am using Logstash to send data to Elasticsearch using jdbc as input which takes data from MySQL table.  Everything is working fine, but I have an issue that whenever I delete the index I don't get the same data back which was in that index. 
 Does Logstash maintain a registry file like Filebeat?

How do I get back the data?  Is there any way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clean_run=> true in your logstash input.This will set sql_last_value to Jan 1, 1970, or 0.

Comment: Your welcome :) You can contact me again in case of any issue